# what is the problem with my tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm going to create 3 table. table "post" and "taxonomy" are connected to "taxonomy_relationship" table with primary key and foreign key but i don't know why do i get this error:
**1005 - Can't create table taxonomy_relationship (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")**

```
CREATE TABLE `post`(
    id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title varchar(255) not null,
    content TEXT not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE `taxonomy`(
    id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tax_title varchar(255) not null,
    type varchar(255) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id, tax_title)
);

CREATE TABLE taxonomy_relationship(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    post_id int not null,
    title varchar(255) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (post_id) 
        REFERENCES post(id) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    FOREIGN KEY (title) 
        REFERENCES taxonomy(tax_title) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

when i use "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS" to show error details it returns:

> >
>   2020-01-19 16:08:31 0x2fb8 Error in foreign key constraint of table `blog`.`taxonomy_relationship`:
>   FOREIGN KEY (title) 
>           REFERENCES taxonomy(tax_title)
>  
>           ON DELETE CASCADE 
>           ON UPDATE CASCADE
>   ):
>   Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
>   referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
>   in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
>   Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
>   tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
>   cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
>   Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/foreign-keys/ for correct foreign key definition.
>   Create  table `blog`.`taxonomy_relationship` with foreign key constraint failed. There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns near 'FOREIGN KEY (title) 
>           REFERENCES taxonomy(tax_title) 
>           ON DELETE CASCADE 
>           ON UPDATE CASCADE
>   )'.

Comment: The error message says it all - you need to have an index in which `tax_title` is the first column in `taxonomy`

Comment: could please help me with fixing the issue. i just don't know what should i do now!

Comment: Just add `INDEX (tax_title)` to the table definition

Comment: A common practice would be to reference `taxonomy(id)` instead of `taxonomy(tax_title)`. There is also probably no point in having `tax_title` as part of the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to add index `KEY title_idx (tax_title)` on `taxonomy` table :

```
CREATE TABLE `taxonomy` (
   `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `tax_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `title_idx` (`tax_title`)
);
```

After you can create foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE taxonomy_relationship(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    post_id int not null,
    title varchar(255) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (post_id) 
        REFERENCES post(id) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (title) 
        REFERENCES taxonomy(tax_title) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Another way you can duplicate `title` in `taxonomy_relationship` but link it by `id` field:

```
CREATE TABLE taxonomy_relationship(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    post_id int not null,
    taxonomy_id int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (post_id) 
        REFERENCES post(id) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (taxonomy_id) 
        REFERENCES taxonomy(id) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: thank u! i just want to know why should i use key? and how many "key" or index can i have in a table?

Comment: Referencing a non unique column (or tuple) is a strange practice.

Comment: I must create index on parent table because `FOREIGN KEY` construction define relation between child and parent table keys. Count of indexes on each table not limited but you need to remember each index give some delay on INSERT/UPDATE operations and take volume on your disk

Comment: See [FOREIGN KEY Constraint Differences](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html): "The handling of foreign key references to nonunique keys or keys that contain NULL values is not well defined for operations such as UPDATE or DELETE CASCADE. You are advised to use foreign keys that reference only UNIQUE (including PRIMARY) and NOT NULL keys."

Comment: @Paul Spiegel You absolutely right and I provided second solution with PRIMAY KEY reference.