# ER_FK_NO_INDEX_PARENT: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint

Tags: mysql

I did read most of the other similar questions and Internet but couldn't fix it yet.

This is what I have :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teams(
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
teamname VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID,teamname)
    )

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players(
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
player_name VARCHAR(255),
cm INT NOT NULL,
teamname VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (teamname) REFERENCES teams(teamname)
    )
```

Full error

> `ER_FK_NO_INDEX_PARENT: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'players_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'teams'`

Both are varchar and foreign key is assigned correctly ( i think so)
Both tables are InnoDB (default)

Comment: You don't have an index on teamname on teams (or a compound index where teamname is the leftmost node)

Comment: @N.B.: Missing index is still confusing for me, after "finding the solution" there is more, applying the solution and understanding the solution, which I fail to. Not everybody

Answer (score 1):

First try to analyze and understand your schema. I don't see a reason, why `teamname` should be part of the primary key. The `ID` column is already unique due to the `AUTO_INCREMENT` option. So you can just make it primary key.

Now analyze the constraints on `teamname`. If two teams cannot have the same name, then you should define a `UNIQUE KEY` constraint on `teamname`. If every team must have a name, then you should define a `NOT NULL` constraint on `teamname`. With these constraints the `teams` can be created as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teams (
  ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  teamname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  UNIQUE KEY (teamname )
);
```

Now you can use the `teamname` column to identify a row in the `teams` table, and can use it as foreign key in other tables. Your code for the `players` table should now work (see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iJ5GncpboURfE673oDCWEA/0)).

Note that usually a foreign key references a primary key of another table. The `players` table would be defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players (
  ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  player_name VARCHAR(255),
  cm INT NOT NULL,
  team_id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES teams(ID)
);
```

When you need to know the team name of a player, you would use a JOIN:

```
SELECT p.*, t.teamname
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN teams t on t.ID = p.team_id
```

Note: In the last few days I've seen questions with the same pattern again and again. The pattern is: A foreign key which references a part of the primary key in onother table. Some examples:

- [what is the problem with my tables in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59810110/what-is-the-problem-with-my-tables-in-mysql)
- [Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59908628/error-code-1822-failed-to-add-the-foreign-key-constraint)
- [#1005 (errno: 150 “Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59901048/1005-errno-150-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed)

Comments and answers suggested to define a simple index on the referenced table to support the FK constraint check. **Don't do that!** Consider if you try to fix your problem by just defining an index on `teamname` on the `teams` table with:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teams (
  ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  teamname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  INDEX (teamname )
);
```

MySQL will accept that (see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5hyEk3nqTgaLoaNapW6W4v/0)). But your schema permits two teams with the same name. Assuming you have two teams with the name "monkeys". And you have a player who has "monkeys" as team name (FK). Which of the two teams is referenced? You can't say! So you better stick to simple rules. And the rule for foreign keys is: Only reference full UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEYS. Or even simpler: Only reference full PRIMARY KEYS. A foreign key value should identify a specific row in the referenced table.